# Scroll the virtualized items control to the bottom

Tags: wpf, scrollview, virtualization, itemscontrol, virtualizingstackpanel

How to scroll the virtualized items control to the bottom when it initially loading?

i have tried this, scroll bar jumps while loading. initially its in middle position and then jumps bottom.. is there is any other way to show the last item in the virtualized items control.

```
    public void ScrollToBottom()
    {
        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
        {
            if (virtualizingStackPanel == null)
            {
                virtualizingStackPanel = Utilities.FindVisualChild<VirtualizingStackPanel>(itemsControl);
            }
            if (this.virtualizingStackPanel != null)
                virtualizingStackPanel.BringIndexIntoViewPublic(this.ViewModel.Items.Count - 1);
        }), DispatcherPriority.SystemIdle);
    }
```

Comment: Just call bringintoview on the last item